# On the Space of Continuous Linear Operators on LCTVS

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a locally convex topological vector space (LCTVS) and that $L(X)$ denotes the space of all continuous linear operators on $X$.

**Question.** How can we construct a topology on $L(X)$ which compatible with the vector space structure of $L(X)$?

I need help on this. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no natural topology on the dual space of a locally convex space unless the original space has a norm. In this case, if the original space is complete, then the $\sup_{B}$ norm is a norm on the dual space. Here $B$ is the unit ball in the original space.

I think the conventional way to endow a topology on the dual space is as follows. Assume $H$ has a topology defined by a family of seminorms such that $\bigcap \{x:p(x)=0\}=\{0\}$. The subbase in this case is all sets of the form $\{x:p(x-x_{0})<\epsilon\}$. So a set $U$ in $H$ is open if and only if at every point $x_{0}\in H$, we have $p_{i},\epsilon_{i},i=\{1\cdots n\}$ such that $\bigcap^{n}_{j=1}\{x\in H:p_{i}(x-x_{0})<\epsilon_{i}\}\subset U$.

Assuming this topology already well defined on $H$, we define a "weak-star topology" on $H^{*}$ by considering the family of seminorms given by $$\mathcal{P}=\{p_{x}:x\in H\}$$where $p_{x}(f)=f(x)$. Since $H^{*}$ is also a topological vector space, the above $p_{x}$ make it into a locally convex space in the same way as $H$. Some author claim that this is the only "natural" topology for the dual space of a locally convex space in the absence of a norm (See Conway). There is also a related personal note by Tao at [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/245b-notes-11-the-strong-and-weak-topologies/).

Comment: My question is actually based on the article of Choe, entitled, "$C_0$-Semigroups on a locally convex space". Let $X$ be LCS whose topology is generated by a family of seminorms on $X$ denoted by $\mathcal{P}$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of bounded sets in $X$ such that span$\left(\displaystyle{\bigcup_{B\in\mathcal{B}}B}\right)=X$. For each $B\in\mathcal{B}$ and $q\in\mathcal{P}$ define $$p_{B,q}(T)=\sup\{q(Tx):x\in B\}$$ for all $T\in L(X)$. Then $$\{p_{B,q}:B\in\mathcal{B}, q\in\mathcal{P}\}$$ is a family of seminorms on $L(X)$ and hence induces a locally convex topology on $L(X)$.

Comment: @juniven: I think this is not substantially different from the topology $C_{b}$, with the compact sets involved. But I still do not see what your problem is - the weak star topology construction still carries through in this case.

Comment: @ user32240, I got what you mean. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not an expert in this area, my guess would be that there is not a *best* or *standard* way of doing this. But I might give some suggestions with my shallow knowledge.

Let's first consider a normed vector space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$, which is a special kind of locally convex topological vector spaces. Then there are some very natural topologies on the space of continuous linear operators $\mathcal{L}(X)$, and we might study how these three topologies can be generalized to a LCTVS.

First, we have the **norm topology** on $\mathcal{L}(X)$ by \begin{equation}
\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|.
\end{equation} Unfortunately I do not know how to generalize this to LCTVS. The problem is that there might be too many seminorms (note that the topology for a LCTVS always comes from a family of seminorms) for the $\sup$ to make sense.

However, if there are only **countably many seminorms**, then $X$ itself is a metric space with a metric $d$. Then of course we might just give $\mathcal{L}(X)$ the sup-norm, viewing it as a subset of $C(X)$, and the norm topology still makes sense.

Secondly, we have the **strong operator topology** on $\mathcal{L}(X)$ if $X$ is normed, which has a local base consisting of sets like \begin{equation}
V(x_1,\dots,x_n;\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n):=\{T\in\mathcal{L}(X):\|Tx_j\|<\epsilon_j\},
\end{equation}or in terms of convergence of nets, $T_{\alpha}$ converges to $T$ in this topology if and only if $T_{\alpha}x$ converges to $Tx$ for all $x\in X$.  Luckily this still makes sense for a general LCTVS.

Similarly, you might consider **other topologies** on $\mathcal{L}(X)$, like weak operator topology and weak$^*$ operator topology, when $X$ is a normed space, and see how they generalize to a LCTVS.